# Portable PHP IDE / Editor

Tags: php, ide

There are a lot of IDE posts here but not for portable.

Can anybody help me find a good portable PHP IDE? I am looking for this features:

1. FTP && SFTP Sitemanager
2. Syntax Highlighting
3. Auto-complete (Optional)

I am fine even with a paid version. I tried aptana on my usb but the experience was not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about [Code Lobster](http://www.codelobster.com) or [Dev PHP](http://devphp.sourceforge.net/) ? they are both great editor with ftp managment, auto-complete, sintax highlighting and even debugging options, and yes, they are both portable.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a portable [gVim](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/gvim_portable). It has a lots of plugins for ftp and sftp. I usualy use it with a portable WinScp together. About the autocomplete: I have it running under the desktop version, but i havent find a way to do that at a portable version. But I get used to snippets like in TextMate. Completion is fine, but I find this solution better.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

http://phpanywhere.net/

Comment: It doesnt support sftp sorry forgot to mention it earlier

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) for the Mac. It has FTP/SFTP/Syntax/Autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

What kind of troubles did you have with Aptana?, because I've made a portable version of Aptana Studio 2 with the original PHP plugin and it works great. I've got instructions and a video on my blog if you want to have a look [here](http://ebenhale.com/blog/)
Or else you could try Filezilla for FTP and Notepad++ for code editing, both these programs are free and can be put on to USB. But with Aptana you get the built in browser and server everything you need in the one package.

Answer (score 0):

Check out JetBrains' "[PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)." I use the Mac OS X version and it's pretty nice! It's also reasonably priced at $99 per individual developer license and there is a 30 day free trial, so you can try it first.

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Text2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2), Just $59 and very powerful editor for any language